# neither vs nor inversion

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

> I have never seen him laugh, nor have I ever seen him lose his temper.

Is there a difference in the use of inversion with "neither" and "nor"? For instance, is it correct to change "nor have I ever seen him lose his temper" to "neither have I ever seen him lose his temper"?

Comment: You need negative inversion either way, but the use of *neither* requires a separate clause: *I have never seen him laugh; neither have I ever seen him lose his temper.* Compare *I have never seen him laugh; I have never seen him lose his temper either.*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use inversion. [Cambridge Dictionaries website](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2) says:

> When a clause with neither or nor is used after a negative clause, we invert the subject and the verb after neither and nor.

It gives one example with neither and one with nor:

> He hadn’t done any homework, neither had he brought any of his books to class.

> We didn’t get to see the castle, nor did we see the cathedral.

Further examples of sentences with "never" can be found in this question: ["Nor" in combination with "never:" Usage and meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342616/nor-in-combination-with-never-usage-and-meaning). These also, in conjunction with the above, justify the validity of "Never ... neither ...", although this is not the question here.

Hence, it is fine to write:

> I have never seen him laugh, neither have I ever seen him lose his temper.

Although using "nor" might be more usual.

Comment: Is the difference not that with *nor* you end up with a single sentence because *nor* is a coordinator, but that with *neither* you end up with two distinct sentences (in terms of the grammar. Not fussing re punctuation etc).